# How to scroll a modal window in Capybara

Tags: selenium, rspec, modal-dialog, capybara

I'm testing with Selenium WebDriver, RSpec and Capybara.

I let the program successfully fill in some fields in a modal window. Now I want to click on a button that is at the bottom of this modal window. At the first glance, I cannot see this button, so Capybara needs to scroll down in the modal window.

The two relevant code snippets of the webpage:

```
<div class = “modal”> </div>
   <button class=”btn …..”> TextOnButton ::after </button>
```

I tried:

```
within('.modal') do
      find('.btn', text: ‘TextOnButton').scrollIntoView(true)
end
```

but received the error message.

> Unable to find visible css ".btn" with text "TextOnButton"

I tried:

```
within('.modal’) do
       page.execute_script 'window.scrollBy(0,100)'
end
```

but then he scrolls the main window but not the modal window.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the HTML snippet there??  Is the button element in the `.modal` or not, and what is the `::after` shown inside the `<button>` element?

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, it works! You are right, it's just a HTML/CSS popup. Sorry for the ambiguous formulation.

Comment: you’re welcome - don’t forget to accept the answer (the check mark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your HTML snippet is incorrect and the button element is actually contained in the modal (as in your text description), then you can try something like

```
within('.modal') do
  btn = find(:button, 'TextOnButton', visible: :all)
  execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', btn)
  btn.click
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This work:

```
execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are already executing code on the modal, but just wondering have you used driver.switchTo().window(handle) to switch to that modal first?

Comment: It's not an actual system modal - it's  just an HTML/CSS popup